# Send data to a parent activity onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Is there a way to send updated data to a parent activity when back is pressed?  I'd like to update the data in the bundle, but I don't see how I would access it.

For example, I have a gallery activity that opens an image viewer.  Say a user scrolls through a dozen images and then backs out to the gallery.  It would be ideal to update the focal image in the gallery with the last image they viewed.

At the moment I can't think of how to do so without a global setting.

Here's pseudo code of what I'd like to do (although this obviously wouldn't work):

Child:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    getIntent().setData(currentImage);  // Not the right intent, obviously
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Parent:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    Uri photoFocus = getIntent().getData();
    if (photoFocus != null)
        setPhotoFocus(photoFocus);
}
```

Comment: Is Galery custom or phone gallery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do

> startActivityForResult()

from your parent activity when you start childactivity. onBackPressed, you can call setResult() in your childActivity.

In parentActivity the code will come to callback :

> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
>   Intent data) { }

where you can extract the result set in setResult method

OR

**use sharedPreferences**

Comment: What a brain fart.  I have a dozen startActivityForResult() cases, but for some reason when I thought about back it didn't occur to me to set a result.  Thanks!

Comment: upvote for pointing out sharedPreferences

Answer (score 2):

**Creating a public class:**

```
public class Values {

    public static Uri uri = null;

}
```

**Child:**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //Set Values.uri here
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

**Parent:**

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    //Get Value.uri here and assign
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try `onSaveInstanceState` instead of `onBackPressed`.

`onSaveInstanceState` gives access to the bundle.

Comment: OnSaveInstanceState cannot be used for navigation. It is used when the system destroys and recreates the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You could also keep the data object as a reference point (static even) and update it in the onBackPressed() method, and in the parent Activity you can fetch that data on the onResume() / onRestart() methods. it's somehow a general concept of bypassing the mechanics of passing data with intents utilizing the lifecycle of activities.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use shared preference to store the data and then fetch it in the parent activity , refer to this post on shared preference [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)