# onActivityResult() not triggered on onBackPressed()

Tags: android, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

I simply want to exchange object information from Activity2 back to Activity1, when "back" button is pressed.
**Everything works fine, except back in Activity1 `onActivityResult(..)` is never triggered.** Therefore I can't access the intent information. Anyone knows why?

I checked out these answers, but they don't work:

[setResult does not work when BACK button pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679250/setresult-does-not-work-when-back-button-pressed)

[How to pass data from 2nd activity to 1st activity when pressed back? - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14292398/how-to-pass-data-from-2nd-activity-to-1st-activity-when-pressed-back-android)

[How to pass the values from one activity to previous activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124548/how-to-pass-the-values-from-one-activity-to-previous-activity)

[Send data to a parent activity onBackPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18438572/send-data-to-a-parent-activity-onbackpressed)

My code (if you need more, tell me):

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.Activity1"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.Activity2"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
```

**Activity1.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // other stuff...

    private void showActivity2(Test test) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
        intent.putExtra("test", test.getSerializableObject());
        startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Test test = data.getExtras().getParcelable("test");
            // Do something...
        }
    }
```

**Activity2.java:**

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    // other stuff....

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("test", test.getSerializableObject());
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: `onBackPressed()` most likely is too late. Call `setResult()` when the user does something positive in your UI to say what it is that they want (e.g., clicks the list item). Usually, you then also call `finish()`, as once the user decided what they want, `Activity2` is no longer needed.

Comment: I also tried to setResult(xxx) while Activity2 is updating something. Still... looks like Activity1 is generally ignoring the callback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per documentation in android for `startActivityForResult`

> Same as calling startActivityForResult(Intent, int, Bundle) with no
>   options.
>
> intent    Intent: The intent to start.
>
> requestCode   int: If >= 0, this code will be returned in
>   onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

Now what you did is this: `startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK);`

Where `Activity.RESULT_OK`actual value is `-1` that is why it is not returning the result.
You need to have a valid request code when you start an activity for result and then filter the request code in your `onActivityResult`.

Comment: Thats correct. Funny, that I already used it correctly in another context...
`startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Photo"), REQUEST_GALLERY);` It is now working correctly! Thx.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned the request code on Activity1.java instead you have written Activity.RESULT_OK which is a result code.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, Activity.RESULT_OK);
```

It should be :

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

REQUEST_CODE should be a final static int value.